# Custom textView not working as expected

Tags: java, android

I have a custom textview as follows

```
public class TaskTitleView extends TextView {
    public static final int NORMAL = 0;
    public static final int DONE = 1;
    public static final int OVERDUE = 2;
    private int mState;

    public TaskTitleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public TaskTitleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TaskTitleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Return the current display state of this view.
     *
     * @return One of {@link #NORMAL}, {@link #DONE}, or {@link #OVERDUE}.
     */
    public int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Update the text display state of this view.
     * Normal status shows black text. Overdue displays in red.
     * Completed draws a strikethrough line on the text.
     *
     * @param state New state. One of {@link #NORMAL}, {@link #DONE}, or {@link #OVERDUE}.
     */
    public void setState(int state) {
        switch (state) {
            case DONE:
                setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                Log.i("vvv","vvvv");
                setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.black));
            case NORMAL:
                setPaintFlags(0);
                setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.black));
                break;
            case OVERDUE:
                setPaintFlags(0);
                setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.red));
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        mState = state;
    }
}
```

On the recyclerView adapter, i did something like this

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.TaskHolder> {

    /* Callback for list item click events */
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View v, int position);

        void onItemToggled(boolean active, int position);
    }

    /* ViewHolder for each task item */
    public class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TaskTitleView nameView;
        public TextView dateView;
        public ImageView priorityView;
        public CheckBox checkBox;

        public TaskHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nameView = (TaskTitleView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_description);
            //nameView= new TaskTitleView(mContext);
            dateView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_date);
            priorityView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priority);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == checkBox) {
                completionToggled(this);
            } else {

                postItemClick(this);
            }
        }
    }

    private Cursor mCursor;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private Context mContext;

    public TaskAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context) {
        mCursor = cursor;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    private void completionToggled(TaskHolder holder) {
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemToggled(holder.checkBox.isChecked(),holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    private void postItemClick(TaskHolder holder) {
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
            int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            mCursor.moveToPosition(adapterPosition);
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(holder.itemView, Integer.parseInt(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.TaskColumns._ID))));
            Log.i("rrr",mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.TaskColumns._ID)));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, parent, false);

        return new TaskHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskHolder holder, int position) {

        Log.i("test", String.valueOf(position));
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        holder.nameView.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.TaskColumns.DESCRIPTION)));
        holder.nameView.setState(0);
        if(mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.TaskColumns.DUE_DATE))==Long.MAX_VALUE)
        {

        }
        else {
            CharSequence formatted = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.TaskColumns.DUE_DATE)));
            holder.dateView.setText(formatted);
        }

        if(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.TaskColumns.IS_PRIORITY)).equals("0"))
        {

            holder.priorityView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_not_priority));
        }
        else
        {
            holder.priorityView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_priority));
        }

        if(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.TaskColumns.IS_COMPLETE)).equals("1"))
        {
            holder.nameView.setState(1);
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.nameView.setState(0);
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mCursor != null) ? mCursor.getCount() : 0;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a {@link Task} for the data at the given position.
     *
     * @param position Adapter item position.
     *
     * @return A new {@link Task} filled with the position's attributes.
     */
    public Task getItem(int position) {
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid item position requested");
        }

        return new Task(mCursor);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getItem(position).id;
    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.close();
        }
        mCursor = cursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Whats wrong, when i change the state, it should change. But i'm just seeing nothing. not even a text.
Please help.
Thanks
...........................................................................
.........................................

Answer (score 0):

You can **add `invalidate();`** when you set state on your custom `TextView` .

```
public void setState(int state) {
    switch (state) {
        case DONE:
            setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            Log.i("vvv","vvvv");
            setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_black));
        case NORMAL:
            setPaintFlags(0);
            setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_blue));
            break;
        case OVERDUE:
            setPaintFlags(0);
            setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_red));
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    mState = state;
    // add here , to update 
    invalidate();
}
```

Change

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == checkBox) {
        completionToggled(this);
    } else {

        postItemClick(this);
    }
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.checkbox:
            completionToggled(this);
            break;
        default:
            postItemClick(this);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, thats not it, Is it corerct how i created the viewHolder for the view

Comment: You can change onClick method and try it .

Comment: And are you changing the state when you click the button or other way ?

Comment: When i click the checkbox, those methods are getting called and database is getting updated with the checkbox value, but im just not able strike the text

Comment: Hi, i fixed it, the problem was becuase of the missing break statement in case DONE:

Comment: Good luck to you .@ams92

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 public class Textview_Bold extends TextView {


    public Textview_Bold(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public Textview_Bold(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Textview_Bold(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Lato-Bold.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }   
}
```

**XML**

```
<yourpackage name.FontText.Textview_Bold
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:text="Create Account"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/createaccount"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change properties in lifecycle of your customView or make your func inside of overrided events.

In your case try to update your view follow next thing:

**View Update**

> From a view lifecycle diagram you may notices that there are two methods that leads view to redraw itself. invalidate() and requestLayout() methods will help you to make an interactive custom view, that may change its look on runtime. But why there are two of them?
>   invalidate() method used to simple redrawing view. While your view for example updates its text, color or touch interactivity. It means that view will only call onDraw() method once more to update its state.
>   requestLayout() method, as you can see will produce view update through its lifecycle just from onMeasure() method. And what it means that you will need it while after your view updates, it changed it’s size and you need to measure it once again to draw it depending on new size.

From here: https://medium.com/@romandanylyk96/android-draw-a-custom-view-ef79fe2ff54b

Comment: Im calling invalidate() in setState method. Shoudnt that suffice

Comment: so try to call requestLayout() in onMeasure() or in setState(), or make all transmodification in onDraw, in setState you must **only set state**, and in onDraw() in case of your state change your view.

Comment: Hi, i fixed it, the problem was becuase of the missing break statement in case DONE:

Comment: write about it)